# Solr error - javax.net.ssl.SSLException (on HTTPS)

Tags: java, ssl, https, solr, ssl-certificate

I'm having a problem with my Solr installation in production. It is configured to run by default on HTTPS.

If I try accessing the Solr dashboard (**api.mydomain.com:8282/solr/#**), the connection times out, but only on port 8282, which Solr uses on my server.

It works fine otherwise (for example, **api.mydomain.com** loads without issue)

I tried to diagnose the problem by running the following on my server

> bin/solr status

I get the following result-

> Found 1 Solr nodes:
>
> Solr process 4365 running on port 8282
>
> ERROR: Failed to get system information from
>   https://localhost:8282/solr due to: javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
>   Certificate for  doesn't match any of the subject
>   alternative names: [*.domain.com, domain.com]

Does anybody know what can cause this error? I've been trying to solve this to no avail.

Comment: If the timeout is got from a remote machine, maybe is there any firewall (in between, or on the server itself).

Comment: About solr status, although it is a local test, it should request api.mydomain.com, and you should have your hosts file configured adequately too